# Can a bounce of Luna's glaive be evaded with normal evasion?

Tags: dota-2

If Luna's moon glaive autoattack hits an enemy and bounces to another enemy that has [evasion](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Evasion) (talisman of evasion, windrun, etc.), does the evasion give that person a chance to dodge the bounce? If it's evaded, does it continue bouncing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not have a source for this, but this is how Moon Glaive interacts with evasion.

1. If the main target evades the attack, there will be no more bounces.
2. If the main target is hit, any secondary target is always hit, regardless of its evasion.

Short version: only the evasion of Luna's initial target makes a difference.